# How to use SignalR with Angular 2?

Tags: signalr, angular

How to use SignalR with Angular 2?

How to manually run change detection when receiving data from SignalR?

Comment: Hi, your question is a bit vague and therefore subject to easily get closed by moderators. Please reformulate your question. Like if you want to learn about change detection, provide some sample code that isn't working for you or which you'd like to get support with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recently wrote an article that demonstrates one way to integrate Angular 2 and SignalR using a "channel/event" model:

https://blog.sstorie.com/integrating-angular-2-and-signalr-part-2-of-2/

I don't think just linking to another site is considered appropriate, so here's the core of the Angular 2 service that exposes SignalR:

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from "angular2/core";
import Rx from "rxjs/Rx";

/**
 * When SignalR runs it will add functions to the global $ variable 
 * that you use to create connections to the hub. However, in this
 * class we won't want to depend on any global variables, so this
 * class provides an abstraction away from using $ directly in here.
 */
export class SignalrWindow extends Window {
    $: any;
}

export enum ConnectionState {
    Connecting = 1,
    Connected = 2,
    Reconnecting = 3,
    Disconnected = 4
}

export class ChannelConfig {
    url: string;
    hubName: string;
    channel: string;
}

export class ChannelEvent {
    Name: string;
    ChannelName: string;
    Timestamp: Date;
    Data: any;
    Json: string;

    constructor() {
        this.Timestamp = new Date();
    }
}

class ChannelSubject {
    channel: string;
    subject: Rx.Subject<ChannelEvent>;
}

/**
 * ChannelService is a wrapper around the functionality that SignalR
 * provides to expose the ideas of channels and events. With this service
 * you can subscribe to specific channels (or groups in signalr speak) and
 * use observables to react to specific events sent out on those channels.
 */
@Injectable()
export class ChannelService {

    /**
     * starting$ is an observable available to know if the signalr 
     * connection is ready or not. On a successful connection this
     * stream will emit a value.
     */
    starting$: Rx.Observable<any>;

    /**
     * connectionState$ provides the current state of the underlying
     * connection as an observable stream.
     */
    connectionState$: Rx.Observable<ConnectionState>;

    /**
     * error$ provides a stream of any error messages that occur on the 
     * SignalR connection
     */
    error$: Rx.Observable<string>;

    // These are used to feed the public observables 
    //
    private connectionStateSubject = new Rx.Subject<ConnectionState>();
    private startingSubject = new Rx.Subject<any>();
    private errorSubject = new Rx.Subject<any>();

    // These are used to track the internal SignalR state 
    //
    private hubConnection: any;
    private hubProxy: any;

    // An internal array to track what channel subscriptions exist 
    //
    private subjects = new Array<ChannelSubject>();

    constructor(
        @Inject(SignalrWindow) private window: SignalrWindow,
        @Inject("channel.config") private channelConfig: ChannelConfig
    ) {
        if (this.window.$ === undefined || this.window.$.hubConnection === undefined) {
            throw new Error("The variable '$' or the .hubConnection() function are not defined...please check the SignalR scripts have been loaded properly");
        }

        // Set up our observables
        //
        this.connectionState$ = this.connectionStateSubject.asObservable();
        this.error$ = this.errorSubject.asObservable();
        this.starting$ = this.startingSubject.asObservable();

        this.hubConnection = this.window.$.hubConnection();
        this.hubConnection.url = channelConfig.url;
        this.hubProxy = this.hubConnection.createHubProxy(channelConfig.hubName);

        // Define handlers for the connection state events
        //
        this.hubConnection.stateChanged((state: any) => {
            let newState = ConnectionState.Connecting;

            switch (state.newState) {
                case this.window.$.signalR.connectionState.connecting:
                    newState = ConnectionState.Connecting;
                    break;
                case this.window.$.signalR.connectionState.connected:
                    newState = ConnectionState.Connected;
                    break;
                case this.window.$.signalR.connectionState.reconnecting:
                    newState = ConnectionState.Reconnecting;
                    break;
                case this.window.$.signalR.connectionState.disconnected:
                    newState = ConnectionState.Disconnected;
                    break;
            }

            // Push the new state on our subject
            //
            this.connectionStateSubject.next(newState);
        });

        // Define handlers for any errors
        //
        this.hubConnection.error((error: any) => {
            // Push the error on our subject
            //
            this.errorSubject.next(error);
        });

        this.hubProxy.on("onEvent", (channel: string, ev: ChannelEvent) => {
            //console.log(`onEvent - ${channel} channel`, ev);

            // This method acts like a broker for incoming messages. We 
            //  check the interal array of subjects to see if one exists
            //  for the channel this came in on, and then emit the event
            //  on it. Otherwise we ignore the message.
            //
            let channelSub = this.subjects.find((x: ChannelSubject) => {
                return x.channel === channel;
            }) as ChannelSubject;

            // If we found a subject then emit the event on it
            //
            if (channelSub !== undefined) {
                return channelSub.subject.next(ev);
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Start the SignalR connection. The starting$ stream will emit an 
     * event if the connection is established, otherwise it will emit an
     * error.
     */
    start(): void {
        // Now we only want the connection started once, so we have a special
        //  starting$ observable that clients can subscribe to know know if
        //  if the startup sequence is done.
        //
        // If we just mapped the start() promise to an observable, then any time
        //  a client subscried to it the start sequence would be triggered
        //  again since it's a cold observable.
        //
        this.hubConnection.start()
            .done(() => {
                this.startingSubject.next();
            })
            .fail((error: any) => {
                this.startingSubject.error(error);
            });
    }

    /** 
     * Get an observable that will contain the data associated with a specific 
     * channel 
     * */
    sub(channel: string): Rx.Observable<ChannelEvent> {

        // Try to find an observable that we already created for the requested 
        //  channel
        //
        let channelSub = this.subjects.find((x: ChannelSubject) => {
            return x.channel === channel;
        }) as ChannelSubject;

        // If we already have one for this event, then just return it
        //
        if (channelSub !== undefined) {
            console.log(`Found existing observable for ${channel} channel`)
            return channelSub.subject.asObservable();
        }

        //
        // If we're here then we don't already have the observable to provide the
        //  caller, so we need to call the server method to join the channel 
        //  and then create an observable that the caller can use to received
        //  messages.
        //

        // Now we just create our internal object so we can track this subject
        //  in case someone else wants it too
        //
        channelSub = new ChannelSubject();
        channelSub.channel = channel;
        channelSub.subject = new Rx.Subject<ChannelEvent>();
        this.subjects.push(channelSub);

        // Now SignalR is asynchronous, so we need to ensure the connection is
        //  established before we call any server methods. So we'll subscribe to 
        //  the starting$ stream since that won't emit a value until the connection
        //  is ready
        //
        this.starting$.subscribe(() => {
            this.hubProxy.invoke("Subscribe", channel)
                .done(() => {
                    console.log(`Successfully subscribed to ${channel} channel`);
                })
                .fail((error: any) => {
                    channelSub.subject.error(error);
                });
        },
            (error: any) => {
                channelSub.subject.error(error);
            });

        return channelSub.subject.asObservable();
    }

    // Not quite sure how to handle this (if at all) since there could be
    //  more than 1 caller subscribed to an observable we created
    //
    // unsubscribe(channel: string): Rx.Observable<any> {
    //     this.observables = this.observables.filter((x: ChannelObservable) => {
    //         return x.channel === channel;
    //     });
    // }

    /** publish provides a way for calles to emit events on any channel. In a 
     * production app the server would ensure that only authorized clients can
     * actually emit the message, but here we're not concerned about that.
     */
    publish(ev: ChannelEvent): void {
        this.hubProxy.invoke("Publish", ev);
    }

}
```

Then a component could use this service by subscribing (not in the rxjs sense...) to a specific channel, and reacting to specific events emitted:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from "angular2/core";
import {Http, Response} from "angular2/http";
import Rx from "rxjs/Rx";

import {ChannelService, ChannelEvent} from "./services/channel.service";

class StatusEvent {
    State: string;
    PercentComplete: number;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'task',
    template: `
        <div>
            <h4>Task component bound to '{{eventName}}'</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="commands">
            <textarea 
                class="console"
                cols="50" 
                rows="15"
                disabled
                [value]="messages"></textarea> 

            <div class="commands__input">
                <button (click)="callApi()">Call API</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class TaskComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() eventName: string;
    @Input() apiUrl: string;

    messages = "";

    private channel = "tasks";

    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private channelService: ChannelService
    ) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // Get an observable for events emitted on this channel
        //
        this.channelService.sub(this.channel).subscribe(
            (x: ChannelEvent) => {
                switch (x.Name) {
                    case this.eventName: { this.appendStatusUpdate(x); }
                }
            },
            (error: any) => {
                console.warn("Attempt to join channel failed!", error);
            }
        )
    }


    private appendStatusUpdate(ev: ChannelEvent): void {
        // Just prepend this to the messages string shown in the textarea
        //
        let date = new Date();
        switch (ev.Data.State) {
            case "starting": {
                this.messages = `${date.toLocaleTimeString()} : starting\n` + this.messages;
                break;
            }

            case "complete": {
                this.messages = `${date.toLocaleTimeString()} : complete\n` + this.messages;
                break;
            }

            default: {
                this.messages = `${date.toLocaleTimeString()} : ${ev.Data.State} : ${ev.Data.PercentComplete} % complete\n` + this.messages;
            }
        }
    }

    callApi() {
        this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe((message: string) => { console.log(message); });
    }
}
```

I tried to map the SignalR concepts into observables, but I'm still learning how to effectively use RxJS. In any case I hope that helps show how this might work in the context of an Angular 2 app.

Comment: this line breaks the code -> this.startingSubject.next(), waiting for a parameter, is it null?

Comment: @Sam Storie: can you make a `node package` (with its config and api) for your wrappers so that they can easily be used for anyone in future?

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi I have thought about it, but honestly I'm not sure if I have the time/energy to maintain such a package. I'm hesitant to throw something out there and just have it linger.

Comment: @SamStorie: well, it would be better than nothing, I guess. anyways, if you do in future, please do update me. P.S: Your blog really helped, thanks a bunch :)

Comment: I keep getting jquery.hubConnection() is not defined. I added reference to jquery typing in signalr. It seems it is simply calling jquery and not signalr. There isn't a $ exported in signalr. Shouldn't you be calling SignalR interface instead of jquery? I apologize that I am double posting this comment.

Comment: My application is separated in two webs: Angular 4 frontend generated by Angular Cli and WebApi 5 backend. I really liked your clean approach but I have some questions. If I can avoid extra libs like ng2-signalr I would prefer it. 1) How do I include and reference jQuery and SignalR to ensure they are bundled by Cli? 2) How do I refer to the generated hubs script if hosted in separate web?

Answer (score 3):

You can also try using **ng2-signalr**.

```
npm install ng2-signalr --save
```

- takes care of ng2 change detection using zones
- allows your server events to be listened to using **rxjs**.

Here is the link to the [source](https://github.com/HNeukermans/ng2-signalr).

Comment: the problem with your implementation is that its not a service.  You cannot create a connection in one place, and then subscribe to server events in multiple components.  You have to disconnect and reconnect each time

Comment: Hi, is your implementation compatible with signalr core?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specified wich syntax you're using to develop your Angular 2 app.

I will assume you're using **typescript**.

One approach is use Definitely Typed files.

1 - You'll need to download a Definitely Typed JQuery:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts

2 - After this, download a Definitely typed SignalR:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/signalr/signalr.d.ts

3 - Add the JQuery refence in your Component:

```
/// <reference path="../jquery.d.ts" />
```

4 - Now, you can call SignalR methods with intelissense. But you will need to use the Late Binding approach:

`var connection = $.hubConnection();
var proxy = connection.createHubProxy(proxy.on("newOrder", (order) => console.log(order));
connection.start();`

Comment: What do you mean by Late Binding approach ?

Comment: It's when you start your signalR __without the generated proxy__: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#genproxy

Comment: @RafaelMiceli I keep getting jquery.hubConnection() is not defined. I added reference to jquery typing in signalr. It seems it is simply calling jquery and not signalr. There isn't a $ exported in signalr. Shouldn't you be calling SignalR interface instead of jquery?

Answer (score 0):

As far as examples go, there probably aren't any yet. Welcome to the beginning of a framework. But do keep checking over time because as popularity and adoption increases, there will sure to be many examples.

As far as running change detection, that's a very vague question as angular2's change detection is now very different, and much improved.

My approach is to just let angular2 handle it, and not trigger a manual change detection at all as most of the time Angular2 picks up on the change and re-renders the view.

If that does not work, then the next step is to trigger `.run()` on the `NgZone`

example:

```
import {NgZone, Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent{
  myProperty: string = 'Hello';
  constructor(myService: MyService, ngZone: NgZone){}

  doSomething(){
    this.myService.doSomething().then(x => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.myProperty = x;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Again though, I have found that even working with asynchronous code, angular2 usually picks up on the change without using ngZone at all.

Comment: Hi. Yeap emerging frameworks are a bit pain in the ass. But i have a feeling like you said, that over the course of this month, Angular 2 will explode exponential. Thanks for this. Will try to make a simple app using NgZone.