# Calling SignalR hub from Angular2 js typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, signalr

I have created onconnected method and messagetoget method in hub. Am using jquery.SignalR_2.2.0.js and Jquery version 1.11.1.

In Asp.net website, am able to establish the connection for hub using below code

var Rep = $.connection.signalHub;
  $.connection.hub.start();

Its calling onconnected method from hub

But when i tried same code in Angular2.js, hub connection is  not establishing.

In website, after  $.connection.hub.start(); statement will call jquery.js function to execute, but in Angular2 jquery.js will not called.
its executing angular.dev.js so here connection is not establish. 
Am new to angular2 and typescript.

for many post i got information is can call like interface in angular2.

Please can anyone help me with example

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34982075/angular-2-and-signalr